# Why did I get the wrong output and how can I fix this?

Tags: c, string, output, character, reverse

I tried to write a program to count the number of occurrences of a given character in a given string.

Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int find_c(char s[], char c)
{
    int count;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        if(s[i] == c)
            count++;
   return count;
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    char s[] = "fighjudredifind";
    number = find_c(s, 'd');
    printf("%d\n",number);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the following output:

```
3
```

since the number of occurrences of the character 'd' in the string s is 3.

Each time I tried to run the program, a different number was displayed on the screen. For example, I got the following output while running the program one time:

```
-378387261
```

And got this output, when running the program another time:

```
141456579
```

Why did I get the wrong output and how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What value is in count before the loop starts?

Comment: @stark I guess that it's 0 since ints are initialized to zero by default in C

Comment: Non-static local (a.k.a *automatic*) variables are not initialized, their value is *indeterminate*. Using them without initialization can lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Automatic variables contain whatever garbage was last on the stack

Comment: @Some programmer dude Thank you! 
I initialized count to 0 and that solved the problem.

Comment: I would still take points off for not explicitly initializing it even if it had been a global.

Comment: @stark I initialized count to 0 before the loop starts and that solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, using `strlen` in each evaluation of the loop bound is superfluous. It would be sufficient to test if the character `s[i]` is the null character. E.g as `s[i] != '\0'` or simply `!s[0]`. `strlen` here runs through the string over and over again and searches for the first occurrence of  `'\0'`.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Your code is good. Only mistake is, you did not initialize the count to 0. If you do not initialize the variable will hold the garbage value and you will be performing operations on that value. As a result, in the earlier case, you got all the garbage values, when you execute the program each time.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int find_c(char s[], char c) {
  int count=0;
  int i;
  for(i=0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    if(s[i] == c)
      count++;
      return count;
}

int main() {
  int number;
  char s[] = "fighjudredifind";
  number = find_c(s, 'd');
  printf("%d\n",number);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and detailed explanation 
It worked!

Comment: @ sreepurna  Of course, actually I've already done that  :)
Thanks!

Comment: @ sreepurna  Yes, you're right. I've just marked it :) 
You've just taught me something new.Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In C Integers are not automatically initialized to zero. 
The problem is that the `count` variable is not initialized.
Try initializing the `count` variable in the `find_c` function to zero.